# Using python to convert a 16 bit number into 2 byte number

Tags: python-2.7

I have 16 bites numbers such as 65303 which I need to convert onto a 2 byte number using Python. Thanks!

Comment: 16 bits is 2 bytes.  I don't think it's possible to decipher what you are asking for.

Comment: How about `x // 256` and `x % 256`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 16 bits number you can compute the lo part (bit 0 to bit 7) and hi part (bit 8 to bit 15) with:

```
n = 65303
lo = n & 0x00ff
hi = n  >> 8
```